Espacio en un jTextfield
Necesito agregar espacios en un jTextfield para poner nombre y apellidos en el mismo jTextfield separados por espacios.
Este es el código que tengo:
Char c = evt.getKeyChar();

if ((c<'a' || c>'z') && (c<'A') || c>'Z') evt.consume();

Character.isWhitespace(c);

Aún así no me da los espacios

Hola. No se entiende cuál es el problema. Y ¿por qué quieres forzar espacios? ¿Cómo se introducen los datos? ¿No es mejor poner el espacio cuando los datos son introducidos, en caso de que lo estés tomando de otros TextFiled o de una fuente cualquiera?

Ese es el problema que al introducir los datos al programa por teclado no me da los espacios en blanco para poner nombre y apellidos en la misma casilla separados por espacios. Muchas gracias

El problema es que únicamente que usas isWhitespace(), deberías usar también event.consume()

isWhitespace() es utilizado para determinar si el carácter
informado es un espacio en blanco o no, devolviendo un valor booleano
de true, en caso de serlo o false, en caso de no serlo.
event.consume() se utiliza para detener el procesamiento de un
evento en Java.

    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    
    //if ((c<'a' || c>'z') && (c<'A') || c>'Z') evt.consume();
    //Character.isWhitespace(c);
    
    if (!Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isWhitespace(c)) { //*Valida permitir letras y espacios.
        evt.consume(); //*  Detiene el procesamiento de caracteres que no sean letras o espacios
    }


Si es un programa que le inserto los datos mediante el teclado  pero no me da los espacios en blanco para poner nombre y apellidos separados por espacios. Muchas Gracias

Y si fuera a introducir solo números?

Debería sustituir isLetter por isNumber?

Usa isDigit()  para validar únicamente números @RogelioLoinazGamez o isLetterOrDigit() si deseas ambos.

Muchas gracias. Este grupo es lo máximo
